# What are the limits of generic functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript

The following compiles cleanly in the Typescript playground but I'd expect it to fail:

```
var f: <T> (arg: T) => T[];
f = <T>(a: T): T => a;
var x: number[] = f(10);
alert('Is an array: ' + Array.isArray(x));
```

Is that expected? Are there docs around what kind of type errors are ignored?

Comment: Which line do you expect to fail and why?

Comment: I should add that `(T) => T[]` has the actual signature `(T: any) => T[]` -- parameter names are required

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried both and got the same result. That's why I omitted `arg: ` in the signature. Made the example more verbose. The thing that seems wrong is that it accepts two incompatible function types in the second line. The rest is just follow-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question

```
var f: <T> (arg:T) => T[];
f = a => a; // Why no error!
```

## Answer

Because in the absence of type annotations `a` is of type `any`. And `any` is compatible with *all types* (simultaneously `T` and `T[]`).

Comment: The problem with the example is that after the first assignment foo is actually not an array but the number 10 (because `f` is the identity function). Even though the type is detected as `number[]`.

Comment: @JanOlafKrems I've updated the answer based on your comment

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Me trying to simplify the original code lead to the `any`. Updated the question to be more precise and contain more complete type annotations.

Comment: The type `T` in `f = <T>(a: T): T => a;` is *uninstantiated* (i.e. cannot be resolved to any concrete type) and therefore treated as `any`.